# Where to Put Files Pertaining to a Project that Aren't Needed for the Build?

Tags: visual-studio, directory-structure

I'm often provided with documents and images detailing the project's design and specifications. During development, I may also create files where I'll plan out the work process. They're the sort of files that I want to keep, but which aren't needed for the build, and which shouldn't really be understood as part of the codebase. They're extra, supporting, meta files.

Thus far, I've been saving such files outside of the directory where Visual Studio (`/source/repos/`) saves my projects, but I don't like separating things this way. I'd prefer to keep everything pertaining to the project in one folder. Is there a best-practice way of achieving this? Is there a folder within VS source directories where it would make sense to place these extra files?